# Construct the vertices of a cube from $ \vec{v} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} (3,1,0) $

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, polyhedra, platonic-solids

The exercise is to construct a cube (inscribed in the unit spher) with one of the corners at: 
$$  \vec{v} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} (3,1,0)  \in S^2 $$

I'm a bit stuck constructing the other seven vertices.  My first guess was to use the eight reflections available to me:

$$ \square \stackrel{?}{=}\left\{  \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{10}} (\pm 3, \pm 1, \pm 0) \right\} $$

This is not quite right since this describes the four vertices of a rectangle in 3-dimensional space.  I remember the rotations of the form a group.  Here is one of the matrices:

$$  \left[ \begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right] \in SO(3) $$

This would lead to the 4 vertices of a square (up to rescaling). Then I am stuck finding the remaining four.

- $ (3,1,0)\;,\; (1,-3,0)\;,\; (-3,-1,0)\;,\; (-1,3,0) $

The algebra would give these vertices, but having the orientation of the cube *slightly off* vertical is enough to confuse my intuition.  Perhaps I could use another matrix:

$$  \left[ \begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0  \end{array}\right] \in SO(3) $$

This generates a few more verties (including some repeats).  This brings the count up to six.

- $ \color{#A0A0A0}{(3,1,0)}\;,\; (3,0,-1)\;,\; (3,-1,0)\;,\; (3,0,1) $

The rotations of the cube are an isometry, so I should be able to generate the cube as the $SO_3(\mathbb{Z})$ orbit of a single vector.  It's hard to decide on paper if I'm on the right track.

**Following the comments**  Here's a third orthogonal matrix:
$$  \left[ \begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & -1  \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0  \end{array}\right] \in SO(3) $$

and we get (up to) three more verices.  So far we have 7 and we're only looking for one more.

- $ \color{#A0A0A0}{(3,1,0)}\;,\; (0,1,-3)\;,\; (-3,1,0)\;,\; (0,1,3) $

We are up to *ten* vertices.  So there is definitely a problem.  There are $|SO(3, \mathbb{Z}) | = 24$ and we're computing the orbit correctly, but we are off a factor of three.  We have obtained three interlocking cubes.

What subset of $SO(3)$ should I be using?

---

Generically the image of a point is the [compound of three cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_of_three_cubes).  So this construction is redundant by a factor of three.

[image]

Let's type out the possible vertices:

```
 a  b  c | -b  a  c | -a -b  c
 a -c  b | -b -c  a | -a -c -b
 a -b -c | -b -a -c | -a  b -c 
 a  c -b | -b  c -a | -a  c  b 

-c  b  a |  c  a  b |  b -a  c 
-c -a  b |  c  b -a |  b -c -a
-c -b -a |  c -a -b |  b  a -c
-c  a -b |  c -b  a |  b  c  a
```

The group theory suggests these should split into three groups of eight, forming the three cubes.  I wasn't able to find the correct permutations.

---

If I had set $\vec{v}_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,1,1)$, then the vertices $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(\pm 1,\pm 1,\pm 1)$ are the vertices of a cube.

Comment: @MathLover Different reflections could have been be used, but now we have to compute three 3 [hyperplanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane).

Comment: $\left[ \begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & 1  \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0  \end{array}\right] \in SO(3)$  what's wrong with this one? I haven't checked it on paper yet (I don't have a paper now), but I believe this one should give you the other vertices.

Comment: @stressed-out it looks orthogonal to me.  I had been nervous from the pair $(3,-1,0)$ and $(-3,1,0)$, they'd be $6$ apart, while the other edges have length $\sqrt{18}$.  I guess they're not adjacent.

Comment: Why do they have to be adjacent? Plus, I think the problem is that you're not doing this systematically. It's easy to find such $3$ matrices, I guess. fix $e_i$ ($i=,1,2,3$) and make it negative and transpose the other two basis vectors. You get a rotation each time and they should work, I believe. Please have a look at what I wrote below. Maybe it's clearer when it can be seen by eyes.

Comment: I don't think using these nice $0,\pm1$ matrices is likely to work -- they are ones that preserve a cube _with axis-parallel sides_, but they _won't_ preserve a cube in the orientation you're looking for here.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I think you are right. I think we need to do what you did. We need to change our cube to the good old cube with top-right corner $(1,1,1)$ and then apply these transformations. Do you agree?

Comment: To echo Henning Makholm’s remark, only one of the other vertices that you generated in the first group of four is a vertex of the cube that you seek. You can certainly generate them all via combinations of a reflection and a 90-degree rotation, but you have to choose the axes carefully. Rotations about the coordinate axes aren’t going to do it.

Comment: Again, I don't think the 24 points you have are a compound of three cubes. For example, if you start with the vector $(1,\varepsilon,0)$ instead, the 24 points you get will be a cluster of 4 points near each of the vertices of an _octahedron_, and there's no set of 8 of such points that make up a cube.

Comment: @cactus314 Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

1) Find the opposite corner: $\vec{w}=-\vec{v} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} (3,1,0)  \in S^2 $

2) Find the vertical axis $A$ of the cube, i.e. the line through the origin which form an angle $\alpha$ s.t. $\cos \alpha=\frac {1}{\sqrt 3}$ with the line $\vec v-\vec w$

3) Find the others 6 corners by the rotation matrix of $\frac {\pi}{2} $around A

[image]

Comment: You sure that $\cos \theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$?

Comment: @cactus314: I think it should be $\frac1{\sqrt3}$.

Comment: ops...yes you are right!

Answer (score 2):

A possible brute-force approach:

Suppose you have orthogonal transformations $T$ and $U$ such that
$$ T(\mathbf e_1) = \frac1{\sqrt{10}}(3,1,0) \\ U(\mathbf e_1)=\frac1{\sqrt3}(1,1,1)$$

Then $T(U^{-1}(\frac1{\sqrt3}(\pm1,\pm1,\pm1)))$ will be a possible solution.

You can construct matrix representations for possible $T$ and $U$ systematically by the Gram-Schmidt process, but simply eyeballing it works too, leading to for example

$$ T=\begin{pmatrix}3 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1/\sqrt{10} \\ & 1/\sqrt{10} \\ && 1 \end{pmatrix} \\
U=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & -2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1/\sqrt{3} \\ & 1/\sqrt{2} \\ && 1/\sqrt{6} \end{pmatrix} \\$$

And inverting the orthogonal $U$ is easy.

Comment: Another possibility is to construct a reflection $R$ in the plane that bisects $\frac1{\sqrt10}(3,1,0)$ and $\frac1{\sqrt3}(1,1,1)$. $R\left(\frac1{\sqrt3}(\pm1,\pm1,\pm1)\right)$ is then also a solution.

Comment: @amd: Indeed; we just need _some_ orthogonal matrix that maps the latter to the former. This was the arithmetically simplest way I could think of constructing one.

Comment: I think what happens I need copy of $SO(3, \mathbb{Z})$ that's *conjugate* to the matrices I have given.

Comment: @cactus314: Well, conjugating each of your matrices with $TU^{-1}$ will give the symmetries of your cube, but you don't actually need those if all you're after is the corners of your cube.